# Hibernate OneToMany bidirectional not recognizing foreign keys

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am working on a faculty project and we are using JPA for database. However, i got stuck on this one-to-many relationship. I am trying to make Waiter with an reference to multiple GuestOrders and GuestOrders with an reference to Waiter but so far unsuccessfully.

- **Waiter owns many GuestOrders**
- **Many GuestOrders belong to one Waiter**

**Waiter**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "waiter")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
@DiscriminatorValue("W")
public class Waiter extends Worker {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="waiter", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Collection<GuestOrder> activeGuestOrders;

    public Waiter() {
        this.activeGuestOrders = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Waiter(String email, String password, String name, String surname,
                  Date bithday, int shoeSize, int dressSize, Role role) {
        super(email, password, name, surname, bithday, shoeSize, dressSize, role);
        this.activeGuestOrders = new ArrayList<>();
    }


    public Collection<GuestOrder> getActiveGuestOrders() {
        return activeGuestOrders;
    }


    public void setActiveGuestOrders(Collection<GuestOrder> guestOrders) {
        this.activeGuestOrders = guestOrders;
    }

    public void addActiveOrder(String newOrder){
        GuestOrder newOne = new GuestOrder(newOrder);
        this.activeGuestOrders.add(newOne);
    }

    public void addActiveOrder(GuestOrder newGuestOrder){
        this.activeGuestOrders.add(newGuestOrder);
    }
}
```

**GuestOrder**

```
@Entity
public class GuestOrder {

    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private long order_id;

    @Column
    private String orders;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private Waiter waiter;

    public Waiter getWaiter() {
        return waiter;
    }

    public void setWaiter(Waiter waiter) {
        waiter = waiter;
    }

    public GuestOrder() {}

    public GuestOrder(String name){
        this.orders = name;
    }
}
```

**Part of code where the addition occurs:**

```
    Waiter newWork = new Waiter(email, password, name, surname, bithday, shoeSize, dressSize,new Role(role));

    newWork.addActiveOrder("Order1");
    newWork.addActiveOrder("Order2");

    repository.flush();
    return repository.save(newWork);
```

What state I end up with is: 
[GuestOrder Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsMZS.png)
[Waiter Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiFas.png)

*Sorry for small pictures.

I have tried every other solution I managed to find by google but it didn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make this work using the cascade, on the @OneToMany, then you have to set the dependencies on both sides of the relationship:

```
Waiter newWork = new Waiter(email, password, name, surname, bithday, shoeSize, dressSize,new Role(role));

GuestOrder order1 = new GuestOrder();
GuestOrder order2 = new GuestOrder();

order1.setWaiter(newWork);
order2.setWaiter(newWork);

newWork.addActiveOrder(order1);
newWork.addActiveOrder(order2);

repository.flush();
return repository.save(newWork);
```

Otherwise the persistence provider will not consider this relationship as fully configured.

Comment: Tried it, and user_id column still stays null.

Answer (score 1):

The GuestOrder is not attached to waiter.Modify as below and try.

```
   public void addActiveOrder(String newOrder){
        GuestOrder newOne = new GuestOrder(newOrder);
        // waiter is now attached
        newOne.setWaiter(this);
        this.activeGuestOrders.add(newOne);
    }
```

Comment: Same as with the solution Maciej provided, user_id column value didn't change

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar problem so I tried [this](https://hellokoding.com/jpa-one-to-many-relationship-mapping-example-with-spring-boot-maven-and-mysql/)
But you will have to deal with endless JSON response.
Maciej Kowalski is correct but here are some changes in `Waiter Class` according to given reference.

```
 public Waiter(String email, String password, String name, String surname,
              Date bithday, int shoeSize, int dressSize, Role role, Collection<GuestOrder> activeGuestOrders) {
    super(email, password, name, surname, bithday, shoeSize, dressSize, role );
    activeGuestOrders.forEach(x->x.setWaiter(this));
}
```

This way you can just declare it in controller in a single line

```
Waiter newWork = new Waiter(email, password, name, surname, bithday, shoeSize, dressSize,new Role(role), activeGuestOrdersCollection );
```